# gsutil rsync "too many values to unpack" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to sync a folder with over 3k files to a bucket on Google Cloud with gsutil. The problem is that less than half of the files are uploaded and then I get this error:

> too many values to unpack
>  CommandException: 1 files/objects could
>   not be copied/removed.

Since Google Cloud support is only available for those who have $200 to spare, does anyone here have a solution that doesn't involve syncing each sub folder individually?

I'm using powershell on windows 10, but this issue also happens on linux. I couldn't find a solution anywhere online.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed in the latest version of gsutil: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/806

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MBen said, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/806), the last comment states:

> v4.40 includes the fix for this bug. The standalone install of v4.40 is now available, and we're waiting on a release of gcloud that includes v4.40 of gsutil. In the mean time, several workarounds have been offered.
>
> That being said, I've locked this thread for the time being, as it's
>   becoming a bit unproductive." - @houglum

One of the simplest workarounds provided is:

> If it helps anyone - downgrading sdk works for me. gcloud components update --version 251.0.0 --quiet
>
> - @Jancis

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty bad bug from Google, and one that I feel could / should have been caught by automated testing